# What should I know to be a polite member of this site?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

After a question has been answered, should I change the title and put `[answered]` in it? What is the proper procedure on this site?

Are there any basic things I should know to be a polite member of this site?

Comment: Neither. First, read the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It gives you most of the information you will need. Then, check out meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum

Comment: @Null You could just say "no"; I don't think he could've asked more politely

Comment: @Michael I guess that came out wrong, but it was just meant to be a statement.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @pisfire! (Even though you haven't created an account here at the time of this writing.) +1 for making the effort to ask instead of just doing whatever you wanted like so many others.

Answer (score 6):

- You don't need to put `[answered]` in
  the title. Just upvote it (if you can) and click the check mark
  next to the answer that solves your
  problem and the number of answers
  (not the background) will show in
  green and the answerer will gain 15 rep.
- Unlike a lot of forums, it's okay to revive old questions (there's even [a badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) for it).
- If you want to comment on an answer, post it as a comment rather than an answer. If it's your own question, you don't need any rep to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The answers you seek (and the answers you don't realize you seek yet) are all contained in the [Official Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ is a good place to start.

For the record: people can see when a question is answered if you point out one of the answers as "the correct one" (see FAQ). People will also appreciate when you use your votes to indicate which answers and questions you find valid/interesting (again, see FAQ).

All the other basic things start with netiquette.

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq),

> Be nice.
>   Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn
>   together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of
>   humor.

To answer your specific question,

> After a question has been answered should I change the title and put answered in it?

No, please don't edit the title to include the answer. Even if the answer will fit into the title field, that's not the proper place for it (nor is putting something to the effect of "resolved" in there either).

There is a facility built into the format called an [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which you should give to the solution that answers your question the best (see the link to find out how to do this). From a list of questions, this gives the question a different colour, implying that the issue is solved or the question is answered.